# javaScript Convert String Array to Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have response from Php Like this

```
"['console.log(\"ok ok \")','console.log(\"pagelet.js loaded\")','','']"
```

its an Array but its string how can i convert it to Array

i thinking about

> split by ,

but i must remove the []
so if any body have another idea 
please Write it :)

also another idea its

> new function

and

> parse

but i dont want to use them now if there are none idea i will use them

Comment: Why not just output something from PHP that makes sense instead, for instance JSON

Comment: i output Json :D but i have some function inside Json i must run them 
so i loaded them scripts as array also and run them functions as array but its and string this is the problem

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by putting function calls in string data?

Answer (score 1):

This would be much simpler not putting function calls in string data and using object properties to accomplish the same thing using client side logic

JSON

```
[{"log": "ok ok"},{"log": "pagelet.js loaded"},{"log":false},{"log":false}]
```

JS (after parsing json)

```
$.each(serverArray, function(_, item){
   if(item.log){
       console.log(item.log);
   }
});
```